# Is it wrong to have multiple associations between classes?

Tags: class, oop, language-agnostic, dependencies, model-associations

I'm modeling a college process, in which I have three classes: **Student**, **Subject** and **Degree**

Degrees have their own subjects, students have a list of subjects they have passed, and also students should belong to a single degree plan.

On a programming perspective, how should I associate a student with his/her degree? Should I pass the degree as a reference to its object, should I make IDs to degrees? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: You should use a Proxy, that basically keeps the degree ID on the student object and builds the Degree object on demand

Comment: I agree to a degree with rodrigo. Create an intermediate object that contains both the Id of the student and the Id of the Degree as well as its own Id.  For the Student-Subject object I would use the new student-degree intermediate object and create another intermediate object that contained the Subject Id and the student-degree Id - phew

Comment: re the above, if i'm not misunderstanidng you, then a Degree per student can have its own uniq set of subjects, rather than a degree having a set of subjects..

Comment: This question asks for opinions. It's not exactly a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> On a programming perspective, how should I associate a student with
>   his/her degree? Should I pass the degree as a reference to its object,
>   should I make IDs to degrees? Is there a better alternative?

I'd suggest it's all rather moot.

ID, index, pointer/reference -- it's all generally the same thing: a lightweight handle to a resource.

One thing that might be relevant is if those handles are opaque or not. For example, an ID or index is definitely opaque. You cannot do anything with them directly except pass them to another interface which does do something. That can be a benefit if your goal is to hide info and decouple entities, though a pointer/reference could potentially be opaque as well (depends on the language). Pointers/references could also be prone to invalidation in ways that IDs and indices are not, but only in lower-level languages like C/C++.

It's worth noting that it can be beneficial to have your outgoing dependencies flow from code that's easier to change towards code that's harder to change. It's because if you require a breaking change to an interface, then having incoming dependencies that are simple to adapt means the change is cheap to make. If, instead, the incoming dependencies are likewise very difficult to change (ex: even harder to adapt in response to the interface change than the interface change itself), then you're looking at a very unpleasant scenario.

Of course, in addition, you want dependencies to flow towards stable interfaces. If you're pretty sure an interface doesn't need to change, then you can be a lot more confident having many/complex outgoing dependencies to it. Both the stability and ease-of-change factor is worth taking into account.

So, for example, if `Students` are very difficult to change and/or not very stable yet interface-wise, and the same holds true for `Degree`, then you might not want to couple either of these directly to the other. Instead you might want to introduce an entity that is simpler than either of these two that depend on both so that if either changes, you only have to change this simpler object in the middle in response. This object might even make the association from student to degree an external association so that your students don't even have to store anything.

I'd suggest it's not so much about multiple associations between classes as how you want the dependencies to flow, and you want them to flow from easy-to-change to hard-to-change, unstable towards stable. It's not the prettiest graph that makes a codebase easier to change/maintain so much as the nature of the connections. One simple thing depending on 3 complex things can be better than 3 complex things depending on each other.

I wasn't quite sure if performance was any part of your question, or merely design/maintainability.

If performance is involved, then naturally you don't want to duplicate any expensive data. Yet none of these lightweight handles described above would do that, as they would not involve any deep copies. Nevertheless, if a `Degree` stores some state that makes it inevitably different per student (meaning we need as many instances as there are students), yet there are bulky parts that aren't unique per student, then we probably want to split that apart into two separate entities, with the per-student degree sharing common data with others to avoid duplication. That is, unless you have a good reason to duplicate like spatial locality or concurrency.